# Why is "/bin/false" required to install the packages?

Tags: command-line, users

I'm installing `ntp` package by giving the configuration as

```
useradd -c "Network Time Protocol" -d /var/lib/ntp -u 87 \
        -g ntp -s /bin/false ntp
```

In the above command what does `/bin/false` signify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this kind of situation, always start from the `man` page.

From `man useradd`:

> -s, --shell SHELL:
>              The name of the user's login shell. The default is to leave this field blank, which causes the system to select the default login
>   shell specified by the SHELL variable in /etc/default/useradd, or an
>   empty string by default.

Setting the user's login shell as `/bin/false` (or `/usr/sbin/nologin`) is another way of saying the user can not login interactively.

Assuming `ntp` is not a physical user, this is fairly common for accounts only needed for services.

Also note that `/bin/false` is an executable (comes with `coreutils` package) that does nothing but exiting with exit status (`$?`) 1 if called.

Another point is, if the `-d` option (creating home directory) is not needed, you can take the safer option to create a system user account.

from `man useradd`:

```
-r, --system
           Create a system account.
```